# Find the most expensive path from s to t using BFS

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

In a given graph `G=(V,E)` each edge has a cost `c(e)`. We have a starting node s and a target node t. How can we find the most expensive path with minimum number of edges from s to t using following BFS algorithm?

```
BFS(G,s):
    foreach v in V do
        color[v] <- white; parent[v] <- nil
    color[s] <- grey; parent[s] <- s
    BFS-Visit(s)

BFS-Visit(u):
    Q <- empty queue
    Enqueue(Q,u)
    while Q != empty do
        v <- Dequeue(Q)
        foreach w in Adj[v] do
            if color[w] white then
               color[w] <- grey
               parent[w] <- v
               Enqueue(Q,w)
        color[v] <- black
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property of BFS is that the set of all nodes at distance `d` from the source is considered just before the set of all nodes at distance `d+1`. Therefore you have to update the "most expensive path" even if a node is grey:

```
BFS(G,s):
    foreach v in V do
        color[v] <- white; parent[v] <- nil; mesp[v] <- -inf
        # mesp[v]: most expensive shortest path from s to v
    color[s] <- grey; parent[s] <- s; mesp[s] <- 0
    BFS-Visit(s)

BFS-Visit(u):
    Q <- empty queue
    Enqueue(Q,u)
    while Q = empty do
        v <- Dequeue(Q)
        foreach w in Adj[v] do
            if color[w] != black and mesp[v] + c(v, w) > mesp[w]:
               color[w] <- grey
               mesp[w] = mesp[v] + c(v, w)
               parent[w] <- v
               Enqueue(Q,w)
        color[v] <- black
```

Comment: +1 thank you, I get the idea. But I am interested in paths that end in a given node t. So we should stop at t and not look at its neighbours. And if we find multiple paths to t, how can we select the path that has minimum number of edges?

Comment: @zabware: When `v = t`, `mesp[t]` will give you the answer. This is a kind of invariant of the algorithm: when the instruction `v <- Dequeue(Q)` is executed, `mesp[v]` _is_ the cost of the most expensive shortest path from `s` to `v` (hence the case `v = t`). You can end the loop whenever `Q` is empty or when you reach `v`: if your graph is connected, in both cases `return mesp[t]` will work.

Comment: so after mesp[w] = mesp[v] + c(v, w) I could simply do If t = v then return mesp[w] else enqueue(q,w)?

Comment: @zabware: No, this could be wrong because there are other nodes at the same distance of `s` that could improve `mesp[w]`. You have to wait until you reach `w` in the outer `while` loop (e.g. `v <- Dequeue(Q) if (v == t) return mesp[t]`). Hence you are sure that you considered all shortest paths to `t`.

Comment: @zabware: If you know how to count the number of shortest paths with a BFS (and understand _why_ it works), this is a very similar idea.

Comment: I want to solve exactly the same problem but using DFS. Would appreciate it if you could help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449625/find-the-most-expensive-path-from-s-to-t-using-dfs