# Find the most expensive path from s to t using DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

In a given graph `G=(V,E)` each edge has a cost `c(e)`. We have a starting node s and a target node t. How can we find the most expensive path from s to t using following DFS algorithm?

```
DFS(G,s):
    foreach v in V do
        color[v] <- white; parent[v] <- nil
    DFS-Visit(s)

DFS-Visit(u)
    color[u] <- grey
    foreach v in Adj[u] do
        if color[v] = white then 
            parent[v] = u; DFS-Visit(v)
    color[u] <- black
```

What I have tried:

So first we create an array to maintain the cost to each node:

```
DFS(G,s,t):
    foreach v in V do
        color[v] <- white; parent[v] <- nil; cost[v] <- -inf
    DFS-Visit(s,t)
    return cost[t]
```

Second we should still visit a node event if it is gray to update its cost:

```
DFS-Visit(u,t)
    color[u] <- grey
    foreach v in Adj[u] do
        if color[v] != black then 
            parent[v] = u;
            if cost[u] < cost[v] + c(u,v) then
                cost[v] = cost[v] + c(u,v)
            if t != v then 
                DFS-Visit(v)
    color[u] <- black
```

and we don't want to go pass t. What do you think? Is my approach correct?

Comment: you know that if you have a loop in your graph, you can create path with infinity total cost.

Comment: @vadikrobot technically that would be a 'walk' not a path.

Comment: @zabware Why are you updating cost[u] when you should be updating cost[v].

Comment: Also, for a 3-node cycle graph, your algorithm shall never terminate since none of the nodes is black initially and DFS-Visit(source) shall also keep getting called.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal hmm so how can I deal with cycles?

Comment: @zabware Are you assuming that the graph doesn't have a positive weight cycle? In that case, your most expensive path will be infinite. In addition, is `c(e) > 0`  or it might be negative as well?

Comment: @A.Sarid c(e) is positive. Unfortunately I have no information about cycles. Using DFS is a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem is NP-Complete. Proof is by a simple reduction of Longest Path Problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem to this.

Proof:
If suppose we had an algorithm that could solve your problem in polynomial time. That is find longest path between two nodes `s` & `t`. We could then apply this algorithm for each pair of nodes (O(n^2) times) and obtain a solution for the Longest Path Problem in polynomial time.

If a simple but highly inefficient algorithm suffices, then you can adapt the DFS algorithm so that at each node, you conduct DFS of its adjacent nodes in **all permuted orders**. Keep track of the minimum cost obtained for each order.

Comment: Isn't this only for finding the longest path in the graph? And not for finding the longest/most-expensive path from a given `s` and `t` ?

Comment: @A.Sarid Look at the reduction proof.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal the running time of the algorithm does not matter in this case. A possible solution needs to be found by modifying DFS.